# Using method from a RestQuery

Tags: android

I'm working on a Android project for someone and I'm working on a Registration activity so I'm trying to use a method from a RestQuery, but the class does not recognize the method even though I imported the RestQuery. Can anyone help me with this? I'm new to Android.

Here is the Register class:

```
package com.RuMad.goveho;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.RuMad.rest.RestQuery;

/**
 * Created by chris on 6/22/13.
 */
public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    private Button mRegister;

    private EditText uName;
    private EditText eM;
    private EditText dob;
    private EditText zCode;
    private EditText pWord;
    private EditText cpWord;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Register");

        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        uName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        eM = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        dob = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        zCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zipCode);
        pWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        cpWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);


    }

    public void onClick (View v){
        String username = uName.getText().toString();
        String email = eM.getText().toString();
        String birthday = dob.getText().toString();
        String zip = zCode.getText().toString();
        String password = pWord.getText().toString();
        String confirm = cpWord.getText().toString();

        boolean invalid = false;

        if (username.equals(""))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else

        if (email.equals(""))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext(), "Enter your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else

        if (birthday.equals(""))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext(), "Enter your birthday", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else

        if (zip.equals(""))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your zipcode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else

        if (password.equals(""))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else

        if (!confirm.equals(password))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This does not match your initial password",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else

        if (invalid == false)
        {
            registerDevice(email,password,device)
            {

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }




}
```

And here is the RestQuery:

```
    package com.RuMad.rest;

import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import com.RuMad.pojos.Device;
import com.RuMad.utils.DateUtil;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Kyle on 6/22/13.
 */
public class RestQuery {

    private static String baseUrl = "https://dev.goveho.com";

    public static void registerDevice(String email, String password, Device device) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("email", email);
            json.put("password", password);
            json.put("device", device.getJsonObject());
            Log.d("register params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/security/device", null, se);
            Log.d("register response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("register", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("register", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("register", "problem calling register", e);
        }
    }

    public static void login(String email, String password, String deviceId) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("email", email);
            json.put("password", password);
            json.put("deviceId", deviceId);
            Log.d("login params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/security", null, se);
            Log.d("login response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("login", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("login", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login", "problem calling login", e);
        }
    }

    public static void logout(String sessionToken, String deviceId) {
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try {
            String response = doDelete(baseUrl + "/services/security", headers);
            Log.d("logout response", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("logout", "problem calling logout", e);
        }
    }

    public static void updateDevice(String sessionToken, String deviceId, Device newDevice) {
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("device", newDevice.getJsonObject());
            Log.d("updateDevice params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPut(baseUrl + "/services/security/device", headers, se);
            Log.d("updateDevice response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("updateDevice", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("updateDevice", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("updateDevice", "problem calling updateDevice", e);
        }
    }

    public static void rideSearch(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String departZip,
                                  int departRadius, String destinationZip, int destinationRadius,
                                  long start, long end) {
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("departureZip", departZip);
            json.put("departureRadius", departRadius);
            json.put("destinationZip", destinationZip);
            json.put("destinationRadius", destinationRadius);
            json.put("start", DateUtil.getDateString(start));
            json.put("end", DateUtil.getDateString(end));
            Log.d("rideSearch params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/ride/search", headers, se);
            Log.d("rideSearch response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("rideSearch", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("rideSearch", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("rideSearch", "problem calling rideSearch", e);
        }
    }

    public static void offerRide(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String name,
                                 String start, String destination, long departureTime,
                                 String timeFlex, String repeat, int maxPassengers,
                                 String category, List<Integer> groups, String info,
                                 boolean onlyVisibleToCollege){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("name", name);
            json.put("start", start);
            json.put("destination", destination);
            json.put("departureTime", DateUtil.getDateString(departureTime));
            json.put("timeFlex", timeFlex);
            json.put("repeat", repeat);
            json.put("maxPassengers", maxPassengers);
            json.put("category", category);
            if(groups!=null && !groups.isEmpty())
                json.put("groups", groups);
            json.put("info", info);
            json.put("onlyVisibleToCollege", onlyVisibleToCollege);
            Log.d("offerRide params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/ride/offer", headers, se);
            Log.d("offerRide response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("offerRide", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("offerRide", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("offerRide", "problem calling offerRide", e);
        }
    }

    public static void requestRide(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String name,
                                 String start, String destination, long departureTime,
                                 String timeFlex, String repeat, int maxPassengers,
                                 String category, List<Integer> groups, String info,
                                 boolean onlyVisibleToCollege){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("name", name);
            json.put("start", start);
            json.put("destination", destination);
            json.put("departureTime", departureTime);
            json.put("timeFlex", timeFlex);
            json.put("repeat", repeat);
            json.put("maxPassengers", maxPassengers);
            json.put("category", category);
//            if(groups!=null && !groups.isEmpty())
            json.put("groups", groups);
            json.put("info", info);
            json.put("onlyVisibleToCollege", onlyVisibleToCollege);
            Log.d("requestRide params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/ride/request", headers, se);
            Log.d("requestRide response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("requestRide", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("requestRide", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("requestRide", "problem calling requestRide", e);
        }
    }

    public static void getMessages(String sessionToken, String deviceId){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try {
            String response = doGet(baseUrl + "/services/user/messages/5", headers);
            Log.d("getMessages response", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("getMessages", "problem calling getMessages", e);
        }
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String subject, String user, String body){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("subject", subject);
            json.put("user", user);
            json.put("body", body);
            Log.d("sendMessage params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/user/messages", headers, se);
            Log.d("sendMessage response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("sendMessage", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("sendMessage", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("sendMessage", "problem calling sendMessage", e);
        }
    }

    public static void myGroups(String sessionToken, String deviceId){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try {
            String response = doGet(baseUrl + "/services/user/groups", headers);
            Log.d("myGroups response", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("myGroups", "problem calling getMessages", e);
        }
    }

    public static void createGroup(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String name){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("name", name);
            Log.d("createGroup params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/user/groups", headers, se);
            Log.d("createGroup response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("createGroup", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("createGroup", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("createGroup", "problem calling createGroup", e);
        }
    }

    public static void viewProfile(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String username){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try {
            String response = doGet(baseUrl + "/services/user/profile/" + username, headers);
            Log.d("viewProfile response", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("viewProfile", "problem calling viewProfile", e);
        }
    }

    public static void joinRide(String sessionToken, String deviceId, int rideId){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("rideId", rideId);
            Log.d("joinRide params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/ride/join", headers, se);
            Log.d("joinRide response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("joinRide", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("joinRide", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("joinRide", "problem calling joinRide", e);
        }
    }

    public static void leaveRide(String sessionToken, String deviceId, int rideId){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("rideId", rideId);
            Log.d("leaveRide params", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
            String response = doPost(baseUrl + "/services/ride/leave", headers, se);
            Log.d("leaveRide response", response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("leaveRide", "problem setting json values", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("leaveRide", "problem creating string entity", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("leaveRide", "problem calling leaveRide", e);
        }
    }

    public static void myDrivingRides(String sessionToken, String deviceId){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try {
            String response = doGet(baseUrl + "/services/user/rides/driver", headers);
            Log.d("myDrivingRides response", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("myDrivingRides", "problem calling myDrivingRides", e);
        }
    }

    public static void myPassengerRides(String sessionToken, String deviceId){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try {
            String response = doGet(baseUrl + "/services/user/rides/passenger", headers);
            Log.d("myPassengerRides response", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("myPassengerRides", "problem calling myPassengerRides", e);
        }
    }

    public static void profileImage(String sessionToken, String deviceId, String username){
        List<BasicHeader> headers = new ArrayList<BasicHeader>(2);
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoSession", sessionToken));
        headers.add(new BasicHeader("X-GovehoMobile", deviceId));
        try{
            byte[] data = doGetBytes(baseUrl+"/services/user/profile/"+username+"/image", headers);
            Log.d("profileImage data", new String(data));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("profileImage", "problem calling profileImage", e);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] doGetBytes(String url, List<BasicHeader> headers) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        setHeaders(httpGet, headers);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        return getResultBytes(response);
    }

    private static String doGet(String url, List<BasicHeader> headers) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        setHeaders(httpGet, headers);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        return getResult(response);
    }

    private static String doPost(String url, List<BasicHeader> headers, StringEntity params) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        setHeaders(httpPost, headers);
        httpPost.setEntity(params);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        return getResult(response);
    }

    private static String doDelete(String url, List<BasicHeader> headers) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getHttpClient();
        HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(url);
        setHeaders(httpDelete, headers);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpDelete);
        return getResult(response);
    }

    private static String doPut(String url, List<BasicHeader> headers, StringEntity params) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getHttpClient();
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
        setHeaders(httpPut, headers);
        httpPut.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
        return getResult(response);
    }

    private static String getResult(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            String jsonString = out.toString();
            return jsonString;
        } else {
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase() + " code="+statusLine.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    private static byte[] getResultBytes(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
            return data;
        } else {
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase() + " code="+statusLine.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    private static void setHeaders(AbstractHttpMessage message, List<BasicHeader> headers) {
        if (headers != null) {
            for (BasicHeader header : headers) {
                message.addHeader(header);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method I'm trying to use is the RegisterDevice method. Also, if anyone has time to answer this, how can I retrieve the Device object information for the RegisterDevice method?

Answer (score 2):

This line of code

```
registerDevice(email,password,device)
```

should be

```
RestQuery.registerDevice(email,password,device)
```

You imported it but you still need to reference it by name.

Comment: +1 for not being stopped by the quantity of code!